# phpStorm - create a template format

Tags: phpstorm

Suppose I have a constant template which is highly frequency typed ,

how could I generate a Shortcut Key which would type this template each time I hit that Shortcut Key ?

**For eample -**

I have the template -

```
<?php echo $myObj->getValue('arg1'); ?>
```

and I want each press on Shortcut Key `Ctrl+c+f` would paste the above template .

Comment: **Live Templates** is the way to go: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/

Comment: Thanks , very helpful video has there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this can have a direct shortcut, but you can insert such code with `ctrl+j cursor and enter`

For that you need to go to

> File -> Settings -> Live Templates

Add another one for your needs. Bonus this way is, you can make a tab stop at the position of arg1 and quickly change that on every insert.